# how I compress and decompress image in java using PCA algorithm?

Tags: java, image-processing

We are doing a Privacy-Assured Outsourcing of Image Reconstruction Service in Cloud project. We want to compress image, then encrypt this compressed image using AES algorithm and store on cloud.
       we are able to compress image using JAI API but we can't decompress this file. we are use following code for image compression.

```
private void compressFile(String realPath, File in, String fileName) {
        BufferedImage input = null;
        try {
            if (fileName.endsWith(".jpg") || fileName.endsWith(".JPG")) {
                RenderedImage img1 = (RenderedImage) JAI.create("fileload", in.getAbsolutePath());
                input = getBufferedImage(fromRenderedToBuffered(img1));
            } else if (fileName.endsWith(".gif") || fileName.endsWith(".GIF")) {
                RenderedOp img1 = FileLoadDescriptor.create(in.getAbsolutePath(), null, null, null);
                input = getBufferedImage(img1.getAsBufferedImage());
            } else if (fileName.endsWith(".bmp") || fileName.endsWith(".BMP")) {
                //  Wrap the InputStream in a SeekableStream.
                InputStream is;
                try {
                    is = new FileInputStream(in);
                    SeekableStream s = SeekableStream.wrapInputStream(is, false);
                    // Create the ParameterBlock and add the SeekableStream to it.
                    ParameterBlock pb = new ParameterBlock();
                    pb.add(s);
                    // Perform the BMP operation
                    RenderedOp img1 = JAI.create("BMP", pb);
                    input = getBufferedImage(img1.getAsBufferedImage());
                    is.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else if (fileName.endsWith(".png") || fileName.endsWith(".PNG")) {
                // Wrap the InputStream in a SeekableStream.
                InputStream is;
                try {
                    is = new FileInputStream(in);
                    SeekableStream s = SeekableStream.wrapInputStream(is, false);
                    // Create the ParameterBlock and add the SeekableStream to it.
                    ParameterBlock pb = new ParameterBlock();
                    pb.add(s);
                    // Perform the PNG operation
                    RenderedOp img1 = JAI.create("PNG", pb);
                    input = getBufferedImage(img1.getAsBufferedImage());
                    is.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (input == null) {
                return;
            }
// Get Writer and set compression
            Iterator iter = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("jpg");
            if (iter.hasNext()) {
                ImageWriter writer = (ImageWriter) iter.next();
                ImageWriteParam iwp = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();
                iwp.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
                float values[] = iwp.getCompressionQualityValues();
                iwp.setCompressionQuality(values[2]);
                String newName = realPath + "/" + "Compress" + fileName;
                File outFile = new File(newName);
                FileImageOutputStream output;
                output = new FileImageOutputStream(outFile);
                writer.setOutput(output);
                IIOImage image = new IIOImage(input, null, null);
                System.out.println(
                        "Writing " + values[2] + "%");
                writer.write(null, image, iwp);
                input.flush();
                output.flush();
                output.close();
                writer.dispose();
                writer = null;
                outFile = null;
                image = null;
                input = null;
                output = null;
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException finfExcp) {
            System.out.println(finfExcp);
        } catch (IOException ioExcp) {
            System.out.println(ioExcp);
        }
    }

    private BufferedImage getBufferedImage(Image img) {


        int w = img.getWidth(null);
        int h = img.getHeight(null);
        int thumbWidth = 330;
        int thumbHeight = 250;

        // if width is less than 330 keep the width as it is.
        if (w < thumbWidth) {
            thumbWidth = w;
        }
        // if height is less than 250 keep the height as it is.
        if (h < thumbHeight) {
            thumbHeight = h;
        }
        //if less than 330*250 then do not compress
        if (w > 330 || h > 250) {
            double imageRatio = (double) w / (double) h;
            double thumbRatio = (double) thumbWidth / (double) thumbWidth;
            if (thumbRatio < imageRatio) {
                thumbHeight = (int) (thumbWidth / imageRatio);
            } else {
                thumbWidth = (int) (thumbHeight * imageRatio);
            }
        }
        // draw original image to thumbnail image object and
        // scale it to the new size on-the-fly
        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(thumbWidth, thumbHeight,
                BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics2D g2d = bi.createGraphics();
        g2d.drawImage(img, 0, 0, thumbWidth, thumbHeight, null);
        g2d.dispose();
        return bi;
    }

    public static BufferedImage fromRenderedToBuffered(RenderedImage img) {
        if (img instanceof BufferedImage) {
            return (BufferedImage) img;
        }
        ColorModel cm = img.getColorModel();
        int w = img.getWidth();
        int h = img.getHeight();
        WritableRaster raster = cm.createCompatibleWritableRaster(w, h);
        boolean isAlphaPremultiplied = cm.isAlphaPremultiplied();
        Hashtable props = new Hashtable();
        String[] keys = img.getPropertyNames();
        if (keys != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
                props.put(keys[i], img.getProperty(keys[i]));
            }
        }
        BufferedImage ret = new BufferedImage(cm, raster,
                isAlphaPremultiplied,
                props);
        img.copyData(raster);
        cm = null;
        return ret;
    }
```

Comment: What specific problem are you having decompressing? It would also be helpful to provide code samples of how you are compressing and encrypting the content and then how you are decrypting and decompressing the content.

Comment: In this project i need                                                                       compress image-->encrypt compressed image-->store on cloud                 and get image from cloude-->decrypt image-->decompress image and get original image.   specific problem is compression and decompression of image

Comment: Please provide the actual code and the specific errors/exceptions you are encountering.

Comment: this is my compression code , i need decompression code?